# jquery slideDown, slideUp wiggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and have problem with one part of my script. basically I am making dropdown div when mouse is over the button, but div starts moving up and down like crazy. here is what i have done: `

```
<script type="text/javascript">
public var boolean opened = false;
$("#drop1").slideUp();
$("#first").mouseover(function(){
        $("#drop1").slideDown();

});
$("#first").mouseout(function(){

     $("#drop1").slideUp();

  });
});
```

also I tried using boolean variable but it gives me error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
public var boolean opened = false;
$("#drop1").slideUp();
$("#first").mouseover(function(){
    if(!opened){
        $("#drop1").slideDown();
        opened = true;
    }
});
$("#first").mouseout(function(){
     if(opened){
     $("#drop1").slideUp();
     opened = false;
     }
  });
});
```

here is HTML if you want, but I think there is everything ok.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
 <div  id="first" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
     <a class="btn" href = "TheShooter/Launcher.exe" ><b>LAN shooter project</b></a>

   <div id="drop1">
     <a href = "TheShooter/index.php"><em>shooter project main page</em></a>                  <br/>
       info: Local Area Network multiplayer game, made with unity. Project                not finished yet, but sometimes fun to play. <br/>
     controls: walking: w,a,s,d<br/>
    shoot: LMB.<br/>
    zoom: RMB.
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help.

--Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you might be more used to strongly typed languages like C#. JavaScript and its library jQuery are loosely typed, meaning you don't declare scope or type. Here's your code above cleaned up a bit to use correct syntax and solve the issues you're seeing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var opened = false;
    // Instead of sliding this up, give the #drop1 element
    // a property of display: none; to start - then remove the line below
    $("#drop1").slideUp();
    $("#first").mouseover(function(){
      if(!opened){
        // Below, I'm using a callback, which means the boolean
        // won't update to true until after the animation is finished
        $("#drop1").slideDown(400, function() {
          opened = true;
        });
      }
    })// Since it's the same element, we can chain events
    .mouseout(function(){
      if(opened){
        // Another callback
        $("#drop1").slideUp(400, function() {
          opened = false;
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about the above!

Comment: yes, I am using C# as my main language in programming :d thanks for your answer!

Comment: btw, what to do if I have 2 or more buttons? do I have to copy paste it like, 10 times?

Comment: Hey Nick, no you wouldn't need to duplicate the code. A better method would be to add a common class between all the sliding elements. So your markup would look something like this: `<div class="slide-element"></div>` repeated however many elements with the same class. Then in jQuery you can add an event to all the .slide-element elements with one declaration. `$('.slide-element').mouseover(function()...`. jQuery returns all elements (in an array) that match the selector.

Answer (score 3):

Hi please refer this fiddle which should answer your question.  No need to add any boolean or conditional checking:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="text">text</div>
<div id="video">video</div>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wrap").mouseover(function(){
   $("#video").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#wrap").mouseout(function(){
   $("#video").slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

and css

```
    #text
{
margin-top:20px;
float:center;
font:VNF-Museo;
font-size:40px;
color: #333;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#video
{
display:none;
width:1024px;
height:278px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#first").mouseover(function(){
     $("#drop1").slideDown("slow");
 });
 $("#first").mouseout(function(){
      $("#drop1").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

See this example above, from the jQuery offical documentation, for more information:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: strange thing happens, when i mouse over top part of "first" and mouse out, everything works fine, but when i do this from bottom it starts wiggling, maybe it's something with div size? but I don't  know why

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more answer with live example,

```js
 

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drop1").mouseover(function(){
            $("#first").slideDown("slow");
        });
        $("#drop1").mouseout(function(){
         $("#first").slideUp("slow");
      });
    });
```

```css
   

 #first, #drop1 {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #acacac;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }

    #first {
        padding: 50px;
        display: none;
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
```

```html
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="drop1">Mouse over on panel to slide down</div>
    <div id="first">Hello Stackoverflow ..!</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but I have already made this with css